# Not able to cast object retrieved from RedisCache in Sprinboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am Springboot 2.7.0 with starter redis and jedis 3.9.0. I am able to store the data in the cache but at time of retrieval it am getting erro `java.lang.ClassCastException`.
Here is redis configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

This is Otp class,

```
@RedisHash(value = "Otp")
public class Otp implements Serializable {
   // fields, setter getters
}
```

Here is Respository code

```
@Repository
public class OtpRepository {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> otpStore;

    public Otp save(Otp otp) {
        otpStore.opsForHash().put("Otp", otp.getOtp(), otp);
        return otp;
    }

    public Otp findByOtp(String otp) {
        return (Otp) otpStore.opsForHash().get("Otp", otp);
    }
}
```

I am getting error while calling fucntion `findByOtp(String otp)`. It is not able to convert Object retrieved from Cache to Otp class. Can someone tell me why is this happening and how can it be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> opsForHash().put("Otp", otp.getOtp(), otp)

you key is "Otp", hash key is otp.getOtp()

the get method parameters should be key, hashkey like below,

```
opsForHash().get("Otp", otp.getOtp())
```

then it will return the otp object you set earlier.